# Pandas : Map the list value in a column to dictionary based on group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which is ,

```
ip_df
     class sec name
0    I     a   ['tom','jim']
1    I     b   ['scooby','joe']
2    II    a   ['peter','sue']
```

I need to map the "name" column as key in a dictionary with a default value as 100 which is like

```
op_df
    class sec  name_marks
0    I     a   {'tom':100,'jim':100}
1    I     b   {'scooby':100,'joe':100}
2    II    a   {'peter':100,'sue':100}
```

I have tried with the apply method, whereas failed to achieve the result like "op_df".

```
op_df = ip_df.groupby(['class', 'sec']).\
                    apply(lambda x: { index : 100 for index in x }).\
                    reset_index(name="name_marks")
```

Comment: Where do all the 100's come from?

Comment: @Aryerez That's a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df['name_marks'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: {k: 100 for k in x})
```